# Detecting spatial autocorrelation within a specific distance

Tags: autocorrelation

If one wants to test if some data is spatially autocorrelated within a distance d, how should one do ?
Is it okay to compute Morans' I and perform a test of significance, taking only pairs of points that are less far away than d ?

Comment: My intuition is that what you propose might work, but I wonder how it might effect the inverse distance matrix. If you only had a few points beyond the threshold d, the distance matrix would take a different form than if you had many poins beyon threshold d.

Comment: I also wonder if there might be a more appropriate technique, such as nearest neighbor analysis given you are comparing pairs of points.  Could you provide a more detailed descripition of your data and the theorized spatial pattern? And do you have a particular weighting scheme you want to use?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The data is growth rates associated to each point on a rectangular plot. I suppose there is positive spatial autocorrelation (and it is the case at the plot scale with a classic Moran's test). The weighting scheme is classical inverse distance. There are many individuals within the distance d.

Comment: The _dnearneigh()_ command in the R _spdep_ package will do this. I've never used that command, though. I _think_ ArcPro also lets you do this.  QGIS has no reliable plug-in to calculate Moran's I.  /////  While I don't have R code that does exactly this, I can post some R code that you could modify. Let me know if that would help.

Comment: @JeffBoggs I am very enthousiast about having some R code, that's what I use !

Comment: The code below assumes you are using a grid and not latitude and longitude or UTM. Let me know if this helps. While the dataset is small, it should do lots of what you want, though you'll have to work in the dneighbor() bit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your code @JeffBoggs. What I understood is that in fact dnearneigh() tells me which point couples fulfill a distance condition (for me, be less than d appart). Then, the way I would use it in Moran's I is to set the weight to 0 in the weight matrix for couples that do not fulfill this condition. Am I right ?

Comment: I _believe_ that will work, but haven't actually tried it for dnearneigh(). You would create the dij.matrix, and then skip directly to using dnearneigh() as outlined here https://r-spatial.github.io/spdep/reference/dnearneigh.html to create the sparse matrix. For instance, close <-  dnearneigh(dij.matrix, 0, 500) if we think that neighbors need to be within 0 and 500 units of each other. Next, you would use lw <- nb2listw(close, style="W", zero.policy=T) to create your sparse matrix (I think). Finally, run Moran's I. Let me know if that works or helps.

Comment: I just tried, the code produces no error, but nb2listw(close, style="W", zero.policy=T) is not what we want to do; Indeed, close is a list, containing for each line of dij.matrix the vector of the column indexes containing values checking the condition. For close <- dnearneigh(dij.matrix, 0, 3) in this example, close[[1]] = c(2). nb2listw() produces weights according to the number of elements of close[[k]] : close[[1]] = c(2) so lw[["weights"]][[1]] = 1, close[[2]] = c(1,3) so lw[["weights"]][[2]] = c(0.5, 0.5), close[[3]] = c(2,4, 5) so  lw[["weights"]][[3]] = c(0.33, 0.33, 0.33) and so on.

Comment: I think I have to do something like dij.matrix2 <- dij.matrix[close] (syntax is wrong of course). I will try this.

Comment: But essentially, this method does what I proposed, i.e. to compute Moran's I only taking into account couples that are less than d appart. This is feasable without spdep I think, but probably less efficiently. I just hope it is stastically relevant to do this.

Comment: and there is an error in my comment, it's dnearneigh(cbind(x,y),0,3) and not dnearneigh(dij.matrix, 0, 3)

Answer (score 0):

```
# R source code to calculate a global Moran's I for point data
# using dataset from Ebdon, David (1985) _Statistics in Geography_,
# 2nd Edition, pages 161-162, Table 7.11.
# 
# Modification of code found at https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-calculate-morans-i-in-r/ .
#
# File created 17 May 2021. Last modified on 25 May 2021.
# Author: Jeff Boggs
#

setwd("D:/Dropbox/DOKUMENTEN/Work/")
getwd()
    

##### READ IN DATA FROM EBDON (1985: 161, Table 7.11):
### First, create individual vectors for ID, x-coordinate, y-coordinate and point measurement (e.g., precipitation in last 24 hours).

id <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
x <- c(2,1,3,4,5)
y <- c(5,4,2,1,1)
z <- c(8,5,10,42,20)

# While we could also save this as a dataframe using...
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, x, y, z))
# ...it is superfluous for our purposes.


### Second, [OPTIONAL] plot locations on a gird:
plot(x,
     y,
     xlim = c(0,6),
     ylim = c(0,6)
     )

# The plot() operation maps points in a Cartesian coordinate system. Here we use it as a diagnostic. Is this map consistent with that that in Ebdon's Table 7.11?

    
##### CREATE INVERSE WEIGHTS MATRIX:
### First, find the distance between each pair of points, the distance between location i and j, and make it a matrix:
dij.matrix <- as.matrix(dist(cbind(x, y)))

dij.matrix2 <- as.matrix(dist(cbind(df$x, df$y))) # should be the same

View(dij.matrix) # compare to part (b) of Ebdon's Table 7.11.
View(dijmarix2) # is this the same?

### Second, calculate the inverse distance matrix:
inv.dij.matrix <- 1/dij.matrix
View(inv.dij.matrix) # compare to part (c) of Ebdon's Table 7.11.


### Third, replace INFINITE values on diagonals with zero.
diag(inv.dij.matrix) <- 0
View(inv.dij.matrix) # now compare to part (c) of Ebdon's Table 7.11

    
##### INSTALL SPDEP AND SP PACKAGES:
# Often, this stage happens first.
# The _spdep_ package includes many spatial statistics, including a global Moran's I. The _sp_ package provides dependencies needed by _spdep_.

install.packages(
  "spdep",
  "sp",
  dependencies = TRUE
  )

library(spdep)
library(sp)

    
##### CREATE SPARSE INVERSE DISTANCE MATRICES FOR _SPDEP_:
# Code cannibalized from https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/troubles-performing-Moran-I-test-td878799.html
# _spdep_ requires our matrix to be converted into a sparse matrix, meaning it only records information about neighbors.


### OPTION 1: Row standardize inverse distance matrix:
lw <- mat2listw(inv.dij.matrix)
lwW <- nb2listw(
  lw$neighbours,
  glist=lw$weights,
  style="W"
  )

# style = "W" row standardizes our matrix. It sums all values in a row, and then divides each value by that sum to replace inverse distances with proportions. As a result, each row sums to one. Compare these two sets of weights:
View(lw$weights) # shows actual inverse distances
View(lwW$weights) # shows row standardized distances. Compare to Ebdon's Figure 7.11, part c, which is not row standaridized.
# Why do we care? This shows what the operation ape::Moran.I does under the hood.
# Q: Why would we row standardize our inverse distance matrix? One reason is that it allows us to see the relative influence of a given cell on a location. Another reason is that eliminates the influence of units of measurement on the results.


### OPTION 2: Do NOT standardize inverse distance matrix:
# This mirrors Ebdon's procedure.
lwW2 <- nb2listw(
  lw$neighbours,
  glist=lw$weights,
  style="B"
  )

#  style="B", which treats the neighbors as binary (i.e., either you are or are not a neighbor), does not standardize the weights. In this instance, it just tells R that everyone is everyone else's neighbors.
View(lwW2$weights) # identical to Ebdon, Table 7.11, part c.


### OPTION 3: Use nb2listwdist() instead of nb2listw
# nb2list() seems to be used more for polygon than point data. The help(nblistwdist) command calculates one of three distance weights: inverse distance, double-power, and exponential distance decay.
# If we use nb2listdist() we can skip some steps, though in the process hiding some of what is happening mathematically.
```

arf <- mat2listw(dij.matrix) # this reads in the distance matrix, not inverse distance matrix
View(arf)
arf2  <- nb2listwdist(
arf$neighbours,
x=SpatialPoints(cbind(x, y)),
type = "idw",
style = "raw")

```
##### CALCULATE GLOBAL MORAN'S I UNDER THE NORMALITY ASSUMPTION:
moran.test(z, lwW, randomisation = FALSE, alternative = "two.sided")

# This result is close, but not identical to the results in Ebdon (1985: 162, Table 7.11, parts e and f). Whereas Ebdon found I = -0.0825, this R code calculates I = -0.05351303. In turn, this alters the Z-score. However, we still fail to reject the null, as did Ebdon.

moran.test(z, lwW2, randomisation = FALSE, alternative = "two.sided")

# This result is nearly identical to Ebdon. Ebdon used no row standardization. The difference is in Z-values, which reflects rounding conventions used to calcualte the observed value and the standard deviation.

moran.test(z, arf2, randomisation = FALSE, alternative = "two.sided")

# This also returns identical results to OPTION 2 using slightly less code.
```